# Confused about the sampling method

Tags: probability, distributions, rejection-sampling, accept-reject

I want to sample from a density using the rejection method. The density is defined as $$ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{e-1},~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1.$$

Following the definition of the rejection method, we can find the rejection constant as:

$\forall t >0 $, $$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \leq C.$$

I chose the exponential function as $g(x)$ so

$$ \frac{e^{x(\lambda+1)}}{\lambda(e-1)} \leq C $$

but I don't know what to do more to compute exactly the rejection constant!

Comment: The obvious envelope is the uniform on (0,1) (scaled up as needed)

Comment: @Glen_b you mean the function $g(t)$ by an envelope ? How did you thought about it? Which intuition led you to choose it?Finally, I choose the exponential because it is kind of similar to the given density. Can I continue the work using my choice ?

Comment: If you draw a picture of the $f$ density, and then just draw a rectangle over the top of it you'll see clearly enough. You can use yours but you'll simply be rejecting points to the right instead of points above; that should work fine.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot...so in this case the rejection constant $C = \frac{e}{e-1}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is find the smallest $C$ such that the inequality is satisfied for all $x \in [0,1]$.  Some straightforward rearranging of our thinking leads to a restatement of the problem as finding the value of $x$ over the interval that maximizes the expression on the left hand side, label it $x_{max}$, which will then generate the desired value of $C$ when fed back into the expression:

$$C = {e^{x_{max}(\lambda+1)} \over \lambda(e-1)}$$

(In some cases there may be no $x_{max}$, e.g., if the interval in question were open and the function had its supremum at one end or the other, but you can see what adjustments would have to be made in such a case.)

We can see this satisfies our requirements by observing that:

$${e^{x(\lambda+1)} \over \lambda(e-1)} \leq {e^{x_{max}(\lambda+1)} \over \lambda(e-1)} = C$$

where the inequality holds by the definition of $x_{max}$.

Since $e^x$ is an increasing function of $x$, clearly $x_{max} = 1$, and plugging that back into the above expression leads to:

$$C = {e^{\lambda+1} \over \lambda(e-1)}$$